# Memcache on ubuntu server lucid and ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcache, rubygems, gem

I'm trying to set up a memcache server on the above setup. I'm getting the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant MemCache (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/clients/memcache_queue_client.rb:18:in `<class:MemcacheQueueClient>'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/clients/memcache_queue_client.rb:14:in `<module:Clients>'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/clients/memcache_queue_client.rb:13:in `<module:Workling>'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/clients/memcache_queue_client.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/remote/runners/client_runner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/remote/runners/starling_runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /root/voicegateway/vendor/plugins/workling/lib/workling/remote.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in load_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `load_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `require_or_load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
from /root/voicegateway/config/environments/development.rb:20:in `block in load_environment'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `block in load_environment'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:379:in `load_environment'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:137:in `process'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /root/voicegateway/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
from ./server:3:in `require'
from ./server:3:in `<main>'
```

But memcache-client 1.8.3 is on the gem list. What's the problem?

Comment: Please post a copy of your config/environment.rb. Also, you will probably get a better answer from stackoverflow.com as this is more a Rails question as opposed to a memcached issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as memcached goes I can help:

```
telnet localhost 11211
stats
quit
```

(`quit` *or* `exit` I always forget that.)

If that doesn't work -- of course replace `localhost` with your real memcached server -- on Ubuntu and Debian the simple `apt-get install memached` will make it available. Since I have *absolutely no idea* what this ruby message means this is just a wild guess.

Also: I took the freedom the question so that it mentions the ruby stuff.